# What is the fastest airplane?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-identification

There are many airplanes that claim to be the fastest piston, private jet, airliner, but what is the all time fastest airplane? How fast does it travel?

Comment: Sorry, I know the question kind of asks for "one" "all-time fastest, period" airplane, and my complicated answer gives a ton. If you want to provide specific definitions for "aircraft" and specify method of propulsion (namely, do rockets count) and any other restrictions (see my question) then I can probably give you one single definitive "fastest ever" answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. The question was for airplane not aircraft, which according to wikipedia is a fixed wing aircraft powered by a jet or propellor.

Comment: Somewhat related, due to the discussion of "relative to what?" is [this xkcd comic](http://what-if.xkcd.com/86/) about what object has traveled the furthest (which thus requires calculations of how fast things travel).  It isn't specifically about aircraft, but still.

Comment: what do you consider to be an airplane?

Comment: @shortstheory Power-driven heavier than air aircraft that produces lift using fixed surfaces.

Answer (score 37):

This is a broad question. The Wikipedia page on [vehicle speed records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vehicle_speed_records#Aircraft) gives a nice breakdown by various categories. Some criteria are manned vs. unmanned, air-breathing vs. rocket, civilian vs. military.

The fastest *manned, air-breathing* aircraft was the [Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird) with an (unclassified) record of [2,193.2 mph on July 28, 1976](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_airspeed_record).

However, some would consider the rocket-powered [North American X-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_X-15) the fastest *manned aircraft* at 4,510 mph.

If you consider the Space Shuttle an "aircraft" during its re-entry phase, it passed Entry Interface at around 17,500 mph. This was unpowered flight though, and its speed dropped off as it entered the atmosphere.

I believe the rocket-boosted [HTV-2 Falcon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTV-2_Falcon) currently qualifies as the fastest *unmanned aircraft* at 13,201 mph.

The record for the fastest human-made craft of any kind is currently held by the [Helios probes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_probes), at 157,078 mph. The fastest *manned* human-made craft was the [Apollo 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_10) spacecraft at 24,790 mph. (Note that Apollo 10 holds the record not because it was any more or less capable than any other Apollo mission, but that its chosen moon fly-by trajectory resulted in a higher top speed relative to Earth. It could also have achieved a much higher top speed on a different trajectory had that been a goal for mission planners, but it wasn't.)

Finally, every single one of these is either military or NASA (not civilian). The fastest *civilian, air-breathing* aircraft were the [Tupolev Tu-144](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-144) supersonic transport at 1,518 mph, and its Western counterpart, the legendary [Aérospatiale-BAC Concorde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde), at 1,488 mph. Both are now retired. Several private organizations are developing civilian suborbital and orbital rocket-powered spacecraft; I'm not sure which is currently fastest.

And though these aren't *crafts* or *vehicles*, honorable mentions go to a [150,000 mph steel plate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob#Propulsion_of_steel_plate_cap) launched by a nuclear weapon, and to particle accelerators for propelling subatomic particles and "man-made" particle collision byproducts at ridiculously close to (99.99something percent of) the speed of light :-)

Comment: [SpaceShipTwo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceShipTwo) (or it's predecessor, SpaceShipOne; I am not sure whether SpaceShipTwo already flew the full planned profile) is civilian and faster than Concorde. It is rocket-powered though, so it leaves Concorde as fastest air-breathing civilian aircraft.

Comment: I wonder what the fastest plane designed for private usage is...  Since Concorde was commercial and all.

Comment: @JayCarr Possibly the [Cessna Citation X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_Citation_X) at Mach 0.935.

Comment: Voyager 1 beats Juno - 3.6 AU / year (or about 38,610 mph) http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/fastfacts.html , but the fastest man-made object was a piece of steel launched at over 147,000 mph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob#Propulsion_of_steel_plate_cap

Comment: @dvnrrs That's right, because civilians aren't allowed to have planes that go super-sonic, are they?

Comment: IF Juno reaches Jupiter, it is projected to reach speeds over 150,000 mph, but that won't happen until sometime in 2016

Comment: @DavidWilkins Touché, I should have said "craft" instead of "object." But in that case I'll put in an argument for the [LHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) (technically the particle collision byproducts are "manmade") :-) And thanks for the correction re: Juno. I thought it had already exceeded Voyager's speed.

Comment: @JayCarr Not exactly. At least one supersonic [MiG-29 is privately owned by a civilian](http://www.eaa.ca/news/2010/2010-12-16_mig29.asp) but I'm not sure if it's been rendered incapable of supersonic flight or whether it can still be legally operated supersonically. Certainly supersonic flight over the continental US is banned (except in certain military areas).

Comment: @dvnrrs Likewise, nice find with Helios, I was unaware.  And it's probably best to not include manmade particles...Every time we turn on our cellphones, light a match, etc.  We're "creating" photons that travel at c

Comment: @DavidWilkins I vote that photons be disqualified since they have zero rest mass. But yes, we are definitely stretching the scope of the original question (not to mention reasonableness) now :-)

Comment: @JayCarr commercial is private :)

Comment: @jwenting - I dunno, there are a lot of things companies are allowed to own that individual people are not...  That's what I was getting at.

Comment: BTW- The protons in the LHC are firmly beaten by the electrons in LEP II (the machine that used to occupy the tunnel the LHC is in) and both are whooped by various neutrino beams in Europe, America and Japan. Not that particle beams are that interesting in this discussion, but just for completeness.

Comment: The [Tupolev Tu-144](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-144), which saw brief civilian passenger service in the USSR, was faster than Concorde.

Answer (score 7):

At present (and since 1976) [Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird) holds record for the fastest aircraft. As mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird#Records):

> The SR-71 was the world's fastest and highest-flying operational
>   manned aircraft throughout its career. On 28 July 1976, SR-71 serial
>   number 61-7962, broke the world record: an "absolute altitude record"
>   of 85,069 feet (25,929 m).

The speed it traveled was **1,905.81** knots (2,193.2 mph; 3,529.6 km/h), approximately Mach 3.3.

[image]

A list of airspeed record is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_airspeed_record).

Comment: SR-71 = fastest *manned, air-breathing* aircraft. Important distinction.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, these are only declassified pieces of information...  For all we know there's some aircraft out there that is significantly faster.

Comment: @JayCarr I don't know that. I am not told any classified information.

Comment: @Farhan - lol, it's just an observation.  If you had access to classified information, I certainly hope you wouldn't share it here ;).

Comment: @JayCarr if he had classified information he'd not even be able to share that he has classified information...

Comment: @jwenting I do have some classified information, but I will not share it because it is called *personal information*. :)

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that the U.S. military ever had a manned air breather faster than the SR-71.

Comment: @JimInTexas [Not yet, anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_SR-72).

Answer (score 2):

The [NASA X-43A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-43) got up to almost Mach 10, I think that's pretty close to a record for an air breathing atmospheric vehicle.