# The SR-71 flew at 2193 mph. Mathematically, how can this be Mach 3.3?

Tags: airspeed, sr-71, mach-number

Virtually every time I read about the [Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird) (including [other threads on this forum](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3692)), I see that its speed record is listed as approximately $2193$ mph.  The same blurb will invariably say this is "about Mach $3.3$". However, when I search for how fast Mach $1$ is, the number that almost always comes up is $767$ mph. Now, $767 \cdot 3.3 \approx 2531$, which is well above $2193$.  If I take $2193$ and divide it by $767$, I get Mach $2.85$.

I doubt I've stumbled on something new here.  So what am I missing? How can $2193$ mph be Mach $3.3$ when $767$ mph is Mach $1$?

Comment: related [What is the reason for changing the speed reference (IAS or Mach number) with altitude?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35408/3394)

Comment: great question, thanks @Joe - whilst I knew that mach is meant to vary depending on air conditions, I did not know the details - and now we have all the details!

Comment: Well you see, multiplication works differently at high altitude..

Comment: Because Mach number as a function of temperature, not physical speed

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The SR-71 was only capable of Mach 3.3 flight at altitude. You can see the limitations in the [pilot's operating handbook(POH) for the aircraft](https://www.sr-71.org/blackbird/manual/5/5-9.php):

[image]

[At higher altitudes the relative speed of sound is lower.](https://www.fighter-planes.com/jetmach1.htm) If we use [this handy NASA calculator](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/sound.html) in a standard atmosphere the relative speed of sound at 70,000 ft. is 660 MPH making your 2193 MPH equal to Mach 3.321

---

Its also important to note that the word "about" is often used as the SR-71 was flown to a maximum compressor inlet temperature(CIT) not a maximum Mach when doing a 3.3 run. [According to the POH](https://www.sr-71.org/blackbird/manual/5/5-8.php)

> Mach 3.2 is the design Mach number. Mach 3.17 is the maximum scheduled
>   cruise speed recommended for normal operations. However, when
>   authorized by the Commander, Speeds up to Mach 3.3 may be flown if the
>   limit CIT of 427°C is not exceeded.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107817/discussion-on-answer-by-dave-sr-71-flew-2193-mph-how-can-this-mathematically-be).